# Key-value pair with unhashable keys

Tags: python

How do I create a key-value pair with unhashable keys, I cannot use a dictionary, as it would give an error,

```
dct = {['a']: 1}
```

would give an error,

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

one alternative is to make pairs in tuple, that is,

```
d = ((['a'], 2), (['b'], 3))
```

but how would I access the value for a particular key, one way to do it is,

```
for i in d:
  if ['a'] in i:
    print(i[1])
```

but is there a faster way to achieve the same?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Why not simply `{'a': 2, 'b': 3}`, with an O(1) lookup? If you're going to say the list may have multiple entries, then repeating the value for multiple keys would still be more efficient than an O(m*n) lookup (although in that case `['a'] in i` wouldn't work anyway).

Comment: Either sort and use `bisect` or use some third-party binary-tree-based `dict`-like (it looks like most of the obvious ones are just a `dict`+sorted `list` though, which would provide no benefits). Are you sure you can't convert your keys to `tuple`?

Comment: Maybe try to change it to `tuple` like this - `dct = {('a,') : 1}`  if you can.

Comment: @DanielHao `('a',)` is a `tuple`, `('a')` is `'a'` with redundant parentheses.

Comment: It's unclear (to me anyway) why you're trying to use a list as a key. Why can't you use *dct = {'a': 1}* ?

Comment: I mean unhashable types of keys in general, which includes list, set, dict and so on

Answer (score 0):

While you could go with converting to tuple as suggested, keep in mind that it will only work if the tuple contains hashable types.

If the value you're going to have are something like `('a', 'b', ['c', 'd'])`, then it will not be hashable.

It's a bit more work, but you could go with having a class and implementing the `__hash__` method.

Something like this, but keep it in mind this is just an example as a starting point (you need to adapt it to your scenario):

```
import hashlib


class HashableList(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        hashlib.md5(str(self).encode(útf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Of course it'd be better to go through the list, check if a type is hashable and recursively do your stuff.
But as I said, as an example this should work.